# Add new column replacing string as value

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a column that has string 'acute' and 'convalescent'. I want to create a new column replacing acute=20 and convalescent=21 number.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

We  can just do an assignment which is vectorized in `base R`

```
df1$newcol <- df1$col1
df1$newcol[df1$col1 == 'acute'] <- 20
df1$newcol[df1$col1 == 'convalescent'] <- 21
```

---

Or in a single line in `base R`

```
df1$newcol <-  with(df1, c(20, 21)[as.integer(factor(col1, levels = c('acute', 
             'convalescent')))])
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <-  data.frame(col1=sample(c('acute','convalescent'), 20,
     replace = T),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ifelse()` which is a vectorized function:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(Var=sample(c('acute','convalescent'),20,replace = T),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Condition
df$Value <- ifelse(df$Var=='acute',20,ifelse(df$Var=='convalescent',21,NA))
```

Output:

```
df
            Var Value
1         acute    20
2         acute    20
3         acute    20
4  convalescent    21
5  convalescent    21
6  convalescent    21
7         acute    20
8         acute    20
9         acute    20
10        acute    20
11        acute    20
12        acute    20
13        acute    20
14 convalescent    21
15        acute    20
16        acute    20
17        acute    20
18 convalescent    21
19        acute    20
20        acute    20
```